# How to create a circular image with border (UIGraphics)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigraphicscontext

How to create a circular image with border (UIGraphics)?

P.S.  I need to draw a picture.

code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_55758514_75sq_1399309159.jpg"];
NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2];
UIImage *profileImg = [UIImage imageWithData:data2];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// Create image context with the size of the background image.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(profileImg.size);
[profileImg drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, profileImg.size.width, profileImg.size.height)];

// Get the newly created image.
UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

// Release the context.
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Set the newly created image to the imageView.
self.imageView.image = result;
```

Comment: What is output of above code?

Comment: The easiest way is to modify the imageView rather than the image. Its most certainly possible to modify the image, but its a ton easier to modify the imageView's .borderColor, .borderWidth, .cornerRadius and .maskToBounds properties ...

Comment: @DavidDoyle I need to draw a picture. `borderWidth` not suitable

Comment: @SpaceInvader, why are the `cornerRadius` or `borderWidth` not suitable? :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like you want to clip the image to a circle.  Here's an example:

```
static UIImage *circularImageWithImage(UIImage *inputImage,
    UIColor *borderColor, CGFloat borderWidth)
{

    CGRect rect = (CGRect){ .origin=CGPointZero, .size=inputImage.size };

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, inputImage.scale); {

        // Fill the entire circle with the border color.
        [borderColor setFill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect] fill];

        // Clip to the interior of the circle (inside the border).
        CGRect interiorBox = CGRectInset(rect, borderWidth, borderWidth);
        UIBezierPath *interior = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:interiorBox];
        [interior addClip];

        [inputImage drawInRect:rect];

    }

    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```

Result:

[image: example before/after]

Comment: Could you post swift version? Thanks

Comment: Which part of the Objective-C version are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: curious why use a c method name rather a OC method name?

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried this ?

```
self.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
```

You'll also need

```
self.imageView.layer.corderRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width/2;
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: The OP was saying in the comments to the question that `.borderColor` and `.borderWidth` is not suitable.

Comment: it looks like OP wants a profile picture in a circle. I bet using borderColor and cornderRadius are the easiest and most common solutions being used out there. Unless there's some super custom drawing need, which it doesn't look like because the code is in viewDidLoad, this should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 version

```
extension UIImage {

    func circularImageWithBorderOf(color: UIColor, diameter: CGFloat, boderWidth:CGFloat) -> UIImage {
         let aRect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: diameter, height: diameter)
         UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(aRect.size, false, self.scale)

         color.setFill()
         UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: aRect).fill()

         let anInteriorRect = CGRect.init(x: boderWidth, y: boderWidth, width: diameter-2*boderWidth, height: diameter-2*boderWidth)
         UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: anInteriorRect).addClip()

         self.draw(in: anInteriorRect)

         let anImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
         UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

         return anImg
     }
}
```